# Excel VBA Add value in blank Cell after specific value

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way in VBA to add a "Z" next to 3 x's within the example below? The cell must be blank after the 3 x's. (Just like the first ID and April below)

[image: Excel Example]

Comment: Yes there is a way - but first, you need to 1. Show us what you've tried so far and 2. Provide a better sample data set (what are the row numbers? what are the columns?).

Comment: Probably worth adding to this question that it's a revision of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50382341/vba-fill-3-blank-cells-next-to-nonblank)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the accepted code in the answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50382341/vba-fill-3-blank-cells-next-to-nonblank):

```
Sub sub1()
  Dim irow&, icol&, n&
  For irow = 2 To 6 ' rows
    n = 0
    For icol = 2 To 14 ' columns
      If Cells(irow, icol) = "" Then
        n = n + 1
        If n <= 3 Then 
            Cells(irow, icol) = "x"
        ElseIf n = 4 Then
            Cells(irow, icol) = "z"
        End If
      Else
        n = 0
      End If
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```